# Convergence of the hypergeometric distribution to the binomial distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics, measure-theory

Suppose p $\in (0,1) $ and $(R_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ con  $0 \le R_{n} \le n$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N},\frac { R_{n} }{ n }  \rightarrow p  
(n \rightarrow \infty) $. Then, for every $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $r \in ${ $ 0,1,...,m $}

$H_{n, R_{n},m}({r})\rightarrow  B_{m,p}({r})$

where $H_{n, R_{n},m}({r}) = \dfrac { \binom{R_{n}}{r}\binom{n-R_{n}}{m-r}}{ \binom{n}{r} } $ and $B_{m,p}({r}) = \binom{m}{r}{p}^{r}{(1-p)}^{m-r}$

I have tried to work with the formulas and I know that I have to arrive to 
$H_{n, R_{n},m}({r}) =  \binom{m}{r}\left(\frac{R_{n}}{n}\right)^{r} \left(\frac{n-R_{n}}{n}\right)^{m-r}$ but I don´t know how to get there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\binom{n}{m}$ should appear in the denominator of the $H_{n, R_{n},m}({r})$ instead of $\binom{n}{r}$.

Consider the binomial coefficients separately. 
$$\binom{R_n}{r}=\frac{ R_n(R_n-1)\ldots(R_n-r+1)}{r!}\sim\frac{R_n^r}{r!}$$ where $a_n\sim b_n$ means that $\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$.
$$\binom{n-R_n}{m-r}=\frac{ (n-R_n)(n-R_n-1)\ldots(n-R_n-(m-r)+1)}{(m-r)!}\sim\frac{(n-R_n)^{m-r}}{(m-r)!}$$
And
$$\binom{n}{m}=\frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-m+1)}{m!}\sim\frac{n^m}{m!}$$

So the initial fraction
$$
\dfrac { \binom{R_{n}}{r}\binom{n-R_{n}}{m-r}}{ \binom{n}{m} } \sim \dfrac{\frac{R_n^r}{r!}\frac{(n-R_n)^{m-r}}{(m-r)!}}{\frac{n^m}{m!}}=\binom{m}{r} \left(\frac{R_n}{n}\right)^r \left(\frac{n-R_n}{n}\right)^{m-r}.
$$

Comment: Oh thank you!, and do you know how to extend this to the convergence of the multivalued hypergeometric? I tried to use induction but it didn't work.

Comment: @MelissaRoblesCarmona Look at point 14 here: http://www.randomservices.org/random/urn/MultiHypergeometric.html